# When will a last-modified date indicate some time in the future?

Tags: http, semantics

[RFC 2616 Section 14.29](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.29) says that if the last modified date is in the *future*, it should be replaced with the message origination date:

> An origin server MUST NOT send a Last-Modified date which is later
>   than the server's time of message origination. **In such cases, where
>   the resource's last modification would indicate some time in the
>   future**, the server MUST replace that date with the message origination
>   date.

The RFC doesn't elaborate any furthur on last modification dates that would indicate some time in the future.

In *what* cases will the resource's last modification date be some time in the future?

What's an example use case / scenario where we will have a resource's last modification date in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't mention it, because it's completely up to the server how resources are implemented.

As a primitive example, consider a server that serves a file system, and encounters a file with a timestamp from the future.